# How can I use order and find_each in neo4j.rb, Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I use Neo4j.rb in Rails. 
I am trying this code.

```
 Person.all.order("n.score").find_each
```

or

```
Person.order(score: :asc).find_each
```

But,its does not get person order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the gem doesn't support that.  You can see [here](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/blob/fceaa39021b81411fb4ff3b7da86c22302c77a9b/lib/neo4j-core/query_find_in_batches.rb#L9) that the order is fixed based on the property which is specified.

That link is from `neo4j-core`, by the way.  You're using either [this](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/13f888a15b4fe5e7ee3101b719e6eba84852f029/lib/neo4j/active_node/query_methods.rb#L45) or [this](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/86f1662e5682156b8f92b97fe7e05f55c42e90dc/lib/neo4j/active_node/query/query_proxy_find_in_batches.rb#L11) for ActiveNode.  Those methods actually continue the hard-coding of the primary key as the ordering.

That said, this might not be necessary.  When I was building the `find_each` / `find_in_batches` functionality I saw Cypher queries as potentially much more complicated than SQL queries because you don't just specify a column.  I'm certainly open to other ideas

Comment: Cool ;)  Again, if you have any thoughts on how to make things better for `ActiveNode` I'm all ears.  Probably the best place for that is a new issue: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/new